# How to dynamically pre-select multiple options based on existing data points

Tags: javascript, html

I have an edit button which gives users the ability to edit a table row;

when the edit button is selected a modal opens where the user can edit their entry in that table row. Included in the edit option is a select dropdown list with categories(all categories) populated. I want the categories(possibly more than 1) pre-selected based on the categories passed in from a json object.

Modal example:

```
File:

name: bob

Title: VP

Category: select dropdown list

cat1 x

cat2 x

cat3 x

cat4

cate5


x -> represents checked items.

description: blahblahblah
```

---

I hope I gave a good enough picture of what i want.

Here is the implementation without the logic of setting up the Selected options:

getData: function(attachmentid) {

```
                $('#edit-attachment-id').val(attachmentid);
                const workorderid = $("#WorkOrderId").val();

                let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('workorderid', workorderid);
                formData.append('attachmentid', attachmentid);


                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetAttachmentInfo")',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: formData,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function(response, status, xhr) {
                        $('#edit-description-input').val(response.Description);
                        $('#edit-title-input').val(response.Title);
                        $('#edit-file-name').text(response.FileName);

                    },
                    fail: function(response, status, xhr) {

                    }
                });
```

**HTML:**

```
<select id="edit-category-dropdown" class="selectpicker" multiple data-selected-text-format="count > 3" data-style="custom-select">
@foreach (var editOption in Model.CategoryOptions){
<option value=@editOption.Key>@editOption.Value</option>}
</select>
```

Comment: Welcome! While iterating the CategoryOptions check if the value is selected then make it true in Option select. CategoryOptions you can keep as `SelectList`.

Comment: I was able to do this by comparing two arrays of keypaired values using underscore library and using the union method. Once I Unioned I used the map method to map the values and pass it in the jquery call 
$('#edit-category-dropdown')
 .val(selectedvalues) 
  .change();